# Will I lose my Nook Stop bonus streak?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I have a pretty good streak going with checking the Nook Stop every day for the bonus miles. However, tomorrow the Resident Services tent will be closed because they are upgrading to a building so I won't be able to check the machine. Is that going to break my streak?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't break your streak. The streak will continue on the next day.

Comment: They actually set your streak to 7+ whether you've reached that or not as a way to say "sorry" for being closed

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading resident services sets your streak to 7+ days as an apology for being closed.  So it won't break your streak.

Resident services is closed on New Years Eve because Tom Nook and Isabelle will be standing out in the plaza for the party.   New Year's Eve **will** break your streak.  You'll have to us the nook stop for 7 days in a row afterwards to re-establish your streak.